# Get night mode from EDSunriseSet

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate

I have sunrise time and sunset time from [EDSunriseSet](https://github.com/erndev/EDSunriseSet), now I need to compare this with current time to get night mode:

```
NSCalendar *todayCal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *todayComp = [todayCal components: NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:[NSDate date]];


BOOL nightMode;

if (todayComp.date > sunriseSet.localSunrise.date & todayComp.date < sunriseSet.localSunset.date) {
    nightMode = NO;

} else {
    nightMode = YES;
    
}


if (nightMode) {
    NSLog(@"the current is night zzzzzzzzzzz PM");
    
} else {
    NSLog(@"the current is day ........... AM");
    
}
```

But it's not working!!

sunrise: 5:18:4 - sunset: 18:41:50

current time: 19:54:13

Comment: what issue are you face

Comment: it's always showing the current is night zzzzzzzzzzz PM

Comment: i test your code by passing static date and it works fine

Comment: Change time to 7:12:35 AM! still showing zzzz PM

Comment: it's working, btw I got NULL from todayComp.date and sunriseSet.localSunrise.date!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code its work well

```
NSCalendar *todayCal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormater dateFromString:@"2017-04-16 05:18:04"];
NSDate *EndDate = [dateFormater dateFromString:@"2017-04-16 18:41:50"];
NSDate *CurrentDate = [dateFormater dateFromString:@"2017-04-16 15:54:13"];

BOOL nightMode;
if (CurrentDate > startDate & CurrentDate < EndDate) {
     nightMode = NO;

} else {
    nightMode = YES;

}
if (nightMode) {
    NSLog(@"the current is night zzzzzzzzzzz PM");
} else {
    NSLog(@"the current is day ........... AM");
}
```